# Swedish dalmål "ö" pronounciation

Tags: ipa

I speak swedish with a heavy dalmål accent and my pronounciation of the swedish ö feels most similar to ɤ̞ in the IPA chart since my tongue is pretty far back. I could not find this mentioned anywhere and am curious why and how common it might be.

Comment: You mean in your pronunciation of Stockholm Swedish and not your pronunciation of Dalecarlian?

Comment: I do not speak Stockholm Swedish, İ guess wikipedia calls it regionally coloured swedish.

Comment: (İ do not know enough of the old languages/dialects to say I speak them, at least not yet)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I guess you are speaking of a vowel in Dalecarlian, which really should be considered to be related to Swedish and not just a dialect. So what are two or three examples of common words with the vowel that you think might be *might* be ö?

Comment: No, you misunderstand. I use the phoneme for almost all occurences of ö. I am very surprised that only the front of mouth ö variants are listed on the page about swedish phonemes. I am speaking of the dialect of swedish spoken in Dalarna, not the ancient languages that managed to survive there. For example "öl", "hög", "röv", "löv".